# acmart aligns tags with column edge, not page edge

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, two-column, acmart

I'm typesetting some equations using the `align*` environment, and I'd like to use the `\tag{}` command to give them textual labels at the end.

However, when I do this with the new `acmart` template, it insists on putting the tags in the middle of the line, and if necessary, on a new line, regardless of how much space there is.

```
\documentclass[sigplan,10pt,review,anonymous]{acmart}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}


\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{align*}
        X & = & Y \tag{good}\\
        X & = & Y \tag{good}
      \end{align*}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
    \begin{align*}
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx & = & YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \tag{bad}\\
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx & = & YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \tag{bad}
      \end{align*}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

What's bizarre is, the problem goes away if I use the one-column ACM format. So I think it must be related to how `acmart` is doing columns. It also doesn't happen in a normal two-column `article`, so it's probably (unfortunately) ACM specific.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and how I can align my tags with the page edge, not column edge?

Comment: Aside: You're abusing the syntax of the `align` environment: It should be `X &= Y \tag{good}`, not `X & = & Y \tag{good}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `align` inside a `minipage` where you can specify the line width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigplan,10pt,review,anonymous]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\sloppy\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure*}
  \begin{align*}
    X &= Y \tag{good1} \\
    X &= Y \tag{good2}
  \end{align*}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX &= YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY \tag{good3} \\
      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY &= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \tag{good4}
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[5-15]

\end{document}
```